# shutil.move removing file extensions

Tags: python

You guys have been a great help with my learning python. I was tasked today with modifying an old employees code and have since downloaded several resources to help. I am renaming files in a folder. Basically a user inputs something in a text box and that is being added on to the end of the file.

```
if len(self.toLoc.get()) == 0:
        searchRev = "_R" + newRev 
        for filename in os.listdir(App.pdfDir):
            sep = searchesri
            rest = filename.split(sep, 1)[0] + searchRev + fromLocation
            shutil.move(os.path.join(App.pdfDir, filename), os.path.join(App.pdfDir, rest))
```

it works perfectly, the only issue i have is that it does not keep the file extensions and unfortunatly there are pdfs and xlsx's in the dir so I can't just hard code pdf on the end. I tried to see if the os function had a way of getting it but i kind of confused myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `searchesri` is, but you're throwing away part of the file name in `filename.split(sep, 1)[0]`.  Maybe you need to append `filename.split(sep, 1)[1]` to the end of your destination file name?

Comment: Thanks! I got it with filePath, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(filename) and appended it on like you said and now I am golden! Appreciate the help.